# Celery: make worker and child processes ( or threads ) share GPU-allocated data

Tags: python, celery, pytorch

In the example below, I allocate a model and tensor on GPU s.t. it is globally visible. I dont' want the child processes to have to copy the data and I don't see why it needs to, since passing the address in the device memory space would be sufficient. ( **throughput is extremely important, and if each child copies the data whenever a request is received, it takes too much time** ). However, when I send a request, I can see ( using `nvidia-smi` ) that the child allocates its own `d0_model` and `d0_in_tensor`.

```py
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

# allocate model and weight on the GPU
d0_model = nn.Conv1d(in_channel, 10, kernel_size).to("cuda:0")
d0_in_tensor = torch.randn(batch, in_channel, out_channel).to("cuda:0")

# task using the model and weight
@app.task
def torch_conv1d(gpu):
    if gpu == 0:
        return d0_in_tensor
```

I don't want my child to have to copy the worker's GPU data, as it puts unnecessary overhead and allocation time.

1. Is there to make the worker process ( or threads, if this is not possible using processes ) and child processes share GPU allocated data?
2. If answer to my first question is "no", then is there a way to pre-allocate each child s.t. they do not have to spend time allocating the model and tensor on GPU ( each child would have it's unique copy of model and tensor, but they would have it allocated when they first spawn and would just hold onto it until a request is received) ?